# Add column to dataframe based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with months going from 1-120 and have written code that looks at which month is in the month column and assigns the year (1-10 in this case):

```
df$Year <- ifelse(df$Month >= 1 & df$Month <= 12*1, '1',
           ifelse(df$Month >= 1+12 & df$Month <= 12*2, '2',
           ifelse(df$Month >= 1+12*2 & df$Month <= 12*3, '3',
                       ...
           ifelse(df$Month >= 1+12*9 & df$Month <= 12*10, '10', NA))))))))))
```

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cut()`.

```
df$Year <- cut(df$Month, seq(0, 120, 12), labels = F)
```

Or `ceiling()`

```
df$Year <- ceiling(df$Month / 12)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `%/%` (integer division) operator. Something like:

```
df$Year <- (df$Month-1) %/% 12  +  1
```

Comment: Do you mean `%/%`?

Comment: Oops, you're right :-) Edited now. %% would give the month number, and %/% would give the year number.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `findInterval`

```
df$Year <- findInterval(df$Month, seq(0, 120, 12))
```